# Removing Sharp Peaks from NDEigensystem Results

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I have an eigensystem I am trying to solve using NDEigensystem, so as a test I am using a different operator which is known to admit to analytical solutions which are smooth(i.e., no discontinuities in the derivative)[for context I am calculating quantum wavefunctions, hence discontinuities in the derivative are unphysical]

The problem I have however is that NDEigensystem gives me messy plots with sharp peaks when I know these should not be present. Is there any way to remove/smooth these sharp points or is this a fundamental limitation of NDEigensystem? If so are there any similar functions I could use for this analysis (although the use of NDEigensystem would be preferable). Any help would be really appreciated! :)

```
H1[\[Rho]_, m_, l_] := 
  R''[\[Rho]] + 1/\[Rho]*R'[\[Rho]] - (m + 1)/l^2*R[\[Rho]] - 
   m^2/\[Rho]^2*R[\[Rho]] - \[Rho]^2/(4*l^4)*R[\[Rho]]; 
H1test = H1[\[Rho], 1, 1];

{PapEvals, PapEvecs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-H1test, DirichletCondition[R[\[Rho]] == 0, True]}, 
   R[\[Rho]], {\[Rho], 0, 50}, 5];
Plot[PapEvecs, {\[Rho], 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MaxRecursion -> 15]
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Probably you need just a finer discretization. One way to obtain one would be `Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0025}}}}`. Here, the suboption `"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0025` is critical.

Answer (score 4):

Like shown in the comments by Henrik, you'd need to refine the mesh

```
H1[ρ_, m_, l_] := 
  R''[ρ] + 1/ρ*R'[ρ] - (m + 1)/l^2*R[ρ] - m^2/ρ^2*R[ρ] - ρ^2/(4*l^4)*R[ρ];
H1test = H1[ρ, 1, 1];

{PapEvals, PapEvecs} = 
  NDEigensystem[{-H1test, DirichletCondition[R[ρ] == 0, True]}, 
   R[ρ], {ρ, 0, 50}, 5, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement",
              {"MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.0025}}}}];
Plot[PapEvecs, {ρ, 0, 20}, PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 100, 
 MaxRecursion -> 15]
```

[image: plot]